# How to drawl an E-R Diagram for the following database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, diagram

I am working on a project and need some help understanding how to create an E-R Diagram.

The requirements are the following:

•  Entities should be drawn that represent each of the tables from the 3rd normalized form.

•  All appropriate fields (i.e., attributes) should be entered into each of the entities.

•  Primary keys (PK) and foreign keys (FK) should be appropriately designated.

•  Data types for each attribute (Numeric, Fixed, Char, Varchar, or Timestamp) should be appropriately designated.

•  Relationships drawn between the entities should be labeled with a relationship name.

I do not understand labeling with a relationship name. Is there also a way to check if my relationships are correct?

Please forgive me I am new to this. I searched online and I get the understanding of many to many and one to many.

Can anyone tell me if my E-R Diagram is correct.
Thanks
[E-R Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eavB.png)

Comment: What you have modeled is a bit off.  Your crow's foot between Customer and Sales Order should only go towards Sales Order.  Read the relationships "A customer may purchase many sales order."  What you have, on the other hand is "A sales order may be purchased by many customers," which I don't believe is correct.  In addition, even if that is what you meant, the DonutOrderID does not exist in your Customer table.  Your relationship between Donut Table and Sales Order Details is backwards and you should not have the Donut ID at all in the Sales Order table.

Comment: As an aside, if your customer can have more than 1 address or 3 phone numbers, your structure violates 3rd Normal.  You also haven't named your relationships, nor have you added the types:  number/int, varchar, char, date, etc.

Comment: How do I name the relationship?

Comment: For example :  from Customer ====< Sales Order, you would name (according to standards) FK_SALESORDER_CUSTOMER for example.  Between SALES_ORDER =====< SALES_ORDER_DETAILS it would be FK_SODETAIL_SALES_ORDER.  All you are doing is naming the foreign key (relationship) and the convention is to name it based on the target table and then the source table.  The primary key for the source migrates to the target.  It can be a little confusing, I know.  I'm not sure why that convention was made, but it is a convention.

Comment: Interesting. I thought of naming such as 1:M or M:M. Is there a tool which I can put the relationship link in and it will tell me if the relationship is valid?

Comment: How does cardinality and modality apply to the relationship?

Comment: You can't actually implement 1:M or M:M as relationship names.  It also doesn't really mean much.  The problem is that you are drawing ~sort of~ an ER diagram and ~sort of~ a data structure diagram.  The crow's feet actually MEAN cardinality and modality.  The "single side" (which in your drawing is simply a "stick" and can be other things) means "1" and the crow's foot end means "M" in a 1:M sort of way.

Comment: Take a look on this site at the "Information Engineering" style, which is the most commonly used.  https://www.smartdraw.com/entity-relationship-diagram/.  It describes cardinality and modality in the way the relationships are drawn.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for all your help